# add the data next to the same numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have four columns of data as follows:

[image]           [image]

how can I add the numbers of the 2 and 4 (1 2 3 4 the numbers for the columns if we consider) corresponding to the same values in 1 and 3 columns?

I mean I want to get these 4 columns in 2 columns in which the values in 2 and 4 columns are added when the values of the 1 and 3 columns are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
H2: =SUMIF($A$1:$A$5,G2,$B$1:$B$5)+SUMIF($C$2:$C$5,G2,$D$2:$D$5)
```

[image]

**NOTE:** *If you will be repeating this process, and if you have more than two pairs of columns, and if the numbers of columns might vary, a Power Query solution might be more useful.*